# Diff Tool That Ignores Newlines

Tags: diff

Looking for a diff tool (preferably with GUI, for Windows, and free, but others are welcome too) that can ignore newlines, so diffs that are only lines joined or broken are ignored. It should also have the option to ignore other "white space only" changes.

For example:

```
void foo(){
    int a=1+2;
```

---

```
void foo()
{
    int a = 1 + 2;
```

These two should compare as "no changes".

(the above is just an example, it should handle all/most textual file types, not just C)

Comment: When it comes to source code I would suggest to apply a source code formatter onto both code files/directories so that formatting changes are ignored.

Comment: That would work in some cases, but I'm looking for a tool to compare unchanged input files.

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073349/compare-source-code-files-ignoring-formatting-differences-like-whitespace-lin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*IntelliJ IDEA* * has a builtin file compare with several options. One of them is "Ignore whitespaces and empty lines" which does what is asked for.

* currently at version 2021.2.2